# Transaction log full with import from CSV to DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw, import-from-csv

I'm trying to upload a CSV file to DB2 with the following command:

```
db2 import from MY_FILE.csv of del insert into TEST.TABLE
```

The file contains more that 2 millions rows. I got `transaction log is full` when I try to upload it.

Is there a way to upload it without getting this error ?

Comment: You could try `LOAD` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup. :)

You can use the `COMMITCOUNT AUTOMATIC` option for [IMPORT](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html). With that option `IMPORT` will determine when your transaction logs will be full and automatically commit the data. That way transaction logs are "cleared" and DB2 is ready for the next chunk of data.